# Dynamically load content in Bootstrap Modal with AJAX with Django

Tags: python, django

I am a begineer in Django framework I want to Dynamically load content in Bootstrap Modal with AJAX
something like this

https://makitweb.com/demo/modal_ajax/index.php

(to be clear its not my code result i want to do dometing like this)

I found many tutorials on internet but i want some guidance on the part where button is pressed and modal shows data related to that item.

Please pardon me if it's a bad question

here is code

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='prodpics', default=None)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length=30)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product

# Create your views here.
def products(request):
    prods = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'products.html',{'prods':prods})
```

## prod.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <!-- <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors"> -->
    <!-- <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v4.0.1"> -->
    <title>Products</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/starter-template/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/starter-template.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light fixed-top">
  <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button> 

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Explore Us</a>
      </li>
      <!-- <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li> -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sign In/Sign Up</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign In</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<main role="main" class="container">

  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Products</h1>
    

  <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        {% for prod in prods %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <img class="card-image-top" src="{{prod.img}}" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-text text-center">{{prod.name}}</h2>
              <p class="card-text text-center">${{prod.price}}</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <!-- <div class="btn-group center"> -->
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Know More</button><br>
                  <!-- Modal -->
                  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{prod.name}}</h5>
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          {{prod.description}}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Request demo</button>
                <!-- </div> -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</main><!-- /.container -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../assets/js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script><script src="{% static 'js/vendor/bootstrap.bundle.js' %}"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this django or bootstrap related question ? You want to learn how to iterate or how to make modals  work?

Comment: its django related problem and the problem is that whenever i click that button on any item i just get the data of first item

Comment: how about showing some code ? how do you iterate over your objects? your template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still this question is related to bootstrap not Django. You should match id's of both button and modal template.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#prod.id">Know More</button><br>
                  <!-- Modal -->
                  <div class="modal fade" id="{{prod.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{prod.name}}</h5>
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          {{prod.description}}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped as i checked in elements but now bootstrap modal is not showing up. Please help me with this too.

Comment: It should work did you check id="{{prod.id}}" shows not undefined?

Comment: it is not showing undefined it is showing id i.e. 6,7,8,9 respectively on different items

Comment: sorry fix this  data-target="#{{prod.id}}"

Comment: it stopped working now modal is not showing up i did everything which is possible but now bootsrap modal is not showing

Comment: it does not stop from anywhere, check developer tools for errors.

Comment: Yeah just worng choice of word I'm not able to find any problem in dev tools here is link of screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J3Hsf4upqaj44t__WEguyubXd5DwR-yU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: there is nothing in console just 4 errors because of image path not connected to it https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NmB3KZdSzF8lYn1HO8bcSrj-Y0bm9icJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: your server is running on port 8001, did you choose that port? i can assume that it has something to do with that port. i,f you are using linux kill port sudo fuser -k 8001/tcp and sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp .. after rerun your server

Comment: Yes I chose that port but modal problem was with port 8000 (default port by django server)

Comment: I dont think so there is nothing to do with that port, it must some kind of browser cache problem, are you using chrome if so try incognito mode.

Comment: so there is nothing wrong with in code with your perspective too let me try in incognito

Comment: I tried in incognito and also in Firefox but problem still exists

Comment: def products(request):
    prods = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'products.html',{'prods':prods}) , try print out prods add a line print(prods)

Comment: i think i know what's wrong with modal, when we are passing data_target="#{{prod.id}}" and id="{{prod.id}}" it is getting id as 6,7 or other int. As i checked by manually passing data_target as string i got modal but when i passed int modal does not showed up so yay! i know the problem

Comment: I know this thread is old, but I solved it by adding a string `id` in  `data-bs-target="#id{{adt.pk}}"` and `id="id{{adt.pk}}"`, hope it help others.